# how to add the home page as a root in rails version 2.3.14?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to the rails programming.

I had a one problem to building a first rails application in rails version 2.3.14.
The problem is , I am not able to add the root in the config/routes.rb file.

I was created the home and about pages. I am trying to add the home page as a root. For that I was added the below line in the routes.rb file.

```
root 'pages#home'
```

But it gives error. The error is,

```
undefined method `root' for main:Object (NoMethodError)
```

It says the root is a undefined method. So, What method is used to add the home page as a root in rails version 2.3.14.

Comment: Since this isn't your first question about being new to Rails and just started learning it: Note that Rails 2.3 is very old and unsupported since 2013, because its successor 3.0 was already released in 2010. I would argue that it doesn't make sense to start learning 2.3 anymore, because newer versions of Rails are significantly different and 2.3 is missing some important features like: the asset pipeline, RESTful routes, the new ActiveRecord query syntax, strong parameters (see this [infographic](http://www.pixelcrayons.com/blog/web/evolution-of-ruby-on-rails-infographic/)). Start with 4.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `map.root` and start upgrading your app to newer version of Rails :)

```
map.root :controller => "pages", :action => "home"
```

Comment: Now also it gives the error. The error is `Status: 500 Internal Server Error`.

Comment: @suresh: What exactly is the error message? In what file does that error happen? What line number, what does the code in that line look like?

Comment: I was found that second error. This is because of the bundlers gem are not included automatically. The error is it cannot able to load the sqlite gem.